# questions- linux server

Tags: linux, partition

How do we define swap partition on a linux server that has several hard disks?
What measure do you think if a linux server crashes then it has the minimum down time?
when we don’t use LVM on linux installation?

Comment: Given that you almost never want your servers to actually use swap all that much, maybe you should skip the swap partition completely and set up a swap file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the second question.

To answer the first: You can create a RAID and define the swap as that RAID device. RAID 1 is probably the best type for swap partitions; RAID 5 is unncessary and RAID 0 doesn't give protection.

Creating a RAID array during install is pretty easy in Debian/Ubuntu. Check out the documenation if you need it at https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/index.html.

Comment: Why would you care about protecting data in a swap file? Do you also take care to ensure you don't lose data in (actual) RAM?

Comment: I'm not an expert on how fault-tolerant RAM is, but I assume if suddenly a gigabyte of RAM memory got 'deallocated', some programs would crash, if not the OS. Am I wrong?

Comment: if some *RAM* disappears, you can expect a kernel crash, but that's not what usually happens with faulty RAM. If some *swap* disappears, the kernel should be unaffected, but programs that happen to have a pointer to a page in the swap are likely to die an unrecoverable death (segmentation fault or bus error, I guess). If some RAM *fails*, programs pointing into it are likely to similarly die; if the kernel happened to be using that RAM, expect a kernel panic or hard lockup.

Comment: @matt.j.alexander: simple, because if you've got something swapped out this stops the program crashing simply because of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many swap partitions as you like across as many hard disks as you like; just set the partition type to Linux Swap, use `mkswap` to format it, and use `swapon` to tell the kernel to use it.

Be sure to add your new swap partitions to `/etc/fstab`.